# Lua os.time function

Tags: java, datetime, lua

so i’m trying to get some values from lua and javascript, i’m using os.time for lua and Date.now for java, but when creating these values they are a little bit different, like java has 3 more digits than lua format. So after reading found a info how java calculete that value since 1970 and lua i cant figure, so in lua i know i can write in os.time a table for him calculate like i can stipulate from where since he can calculate, but my doubt is how i can parse that table?!
Like:

```lua
Local table = Year, month , day, hour, minute, seconds
os.time(table)
```

So my doubt is, how i can do to get the same values in lua and java?

I want just a simple function to get same value in lua and java.
Tks for your help!

Comment: Is one seconds and the other milliseconds?

Comment: "... i’m trying to get some values from lua and javascript, i’m using os.time for lua and Date.now for java, ..." -- javascript is not java. do you want javascript or java?

Comment: If it was Javascript, it'd explain the `Date.now()`. As far as I can see, Java's `Date` doesn't have a `now` method.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what function you're referring to by `Date.now` but in Java `new Date().time` will give you the current time in ms (since Jan 1 1970) and lua will give you the same number to the nearest second. To convert from Java, divide by 1000. You can't convert precisely the other way but multiplying by 1000 will get you to the nearest second.

Comment: Ok, now i has a new doubt is possible update a info showed in a website? like i'm sending that info of milisecs to a webpage, but it dosnt updated. any way to make a loop in javascript?

Comment: @bazante It’s not my home field, but I think you will want to look into Ajax and JSON. Holloway, please forget about the `Date` class. It’s old and poorly designed. The way to get the whole second in Java is `Instant.now().getEpochSecond()`.